# Make an imageview appear and disappear smoothy

Tags: android-animation

I want to animate the visibility property of a view so that it appears/disappears smoothly.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "appears and disappears smoothly"? (Fading in and out? Sliding on and off the screen?)

Comment: @ Gareth: i want the image in imageview get more and more transparent than set it's visibility to View.Gone and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to animate the Alpha value than you should look at [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)

see link below for more help:

1. [Android Animation](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-2/)